# Rails Field Error Proc not working properly when using any tag other than label with client_side_validation gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, label, client-side-validation

I have a Rails 3.0.10 project that is using the client_side_validations gem to validate form input on each field before form submission. I am using the field_error_proc block to override the field_with_errors output to give inline messages for each field. This code does work, but the use of the label tag limits the amount of styling that can be done. I would like to style the message in some way but it will NOT allow me to use any other tag other than label... not span or div.

If I change the tag to something other than label the variable named "instance" has blank attributes. I have tried to assign the values to other variables but this also does not work...it only seems to have the proper values if I use a label tag. I have absolutely no idea how this could be so brittle. Below is the code I am using:

```
ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = Proc.new do |html_tag, instance|
  unless html_tag =~ /^<label/
    %{
      <div class="field_with_errors">
        <label for="#{instance.send(:tag_id)}" class="message">#{instance.error_message.first}</label>
        #{html_tag}
      </div>
    }.html_safe
  else
    %{
      <div class="field_with_errors">
        #{html_tag}
      </div>
    }.html_safe
  end
end
```

Comment: No, but I have since put the project this pertains to on hold. It's possible that it has been fixed in a later version of rails. Anyone care to comment?